# Dynamic value graph creation in yii2 using GoogleChart?

Tags: yii2

Here I wanna draw line chart graph by dynamic value.but in my case for every value of array created different different graph...Please help me I am first time do this task.Thanks in Advances

```
<?php

$modelEmployee=Employee::find()->select(['id','sales','expenses'])->all();
$arr = array('id'=>array(),
            'sales'=>array(),
            'expenses'=>array());
for($i = 0, $modEm = $modelEmployee; $i < sizeof($modelEmployee); $i++){
    $arr['id'] = $modEm[$i]['id'];
    $arr['sales'] = $modEm[$i]['sales'];
    $arr['expenses'] = $modEm[$i]['expenses'];
print_r($arr);
    echo GoogleChart::widget(array('visualization' => 'LineChart',
                 'data' => array(
            array('Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'),
            array($arr['id'],$arr['sales'],$arr['expenses']),

    ),
                'options' => array(
                    'title' => 'My Company Performance2',
                    'titleTextStyle' => array('color' => '#FF0000'),
                    'vAxis' => array(
                        'title' => 'Scott vAxis',
                        'gridlines' => array(
                            'color' => 'transparent'  //set grid line transparent
                        )),
                    'hAxis' => array('title' => 'Scott hAixs'),
                    'curveType' => 'function', //smooth curve or not
                    'legend' => array('position' => 'bottom'),
                )));

?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all the multiple graphs are because you are doing echo inside for loop so it will take only one value and create graph from that.

you have to create an array of values and pass it to the graph widget as following

```
$graph_data = [];
$graph_data[] = array('Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'); 

for($i = 0, $modEm = $modelEmployee; $i < sizeof($modelEmployee); $i++){
 $arr['id'] = $modEm[$i]['id'];
 $arr['sales'] = $modEm[$i]['sales'];
 $arr['expenses'] = $modEm[$i]['expenses'];
 $graph_data[] = array($arr['id'],$arr['sales'],$arr['expenses']); //add the values you require as set in the order of Year, Sales , Expenses
} //loop ends here
echo GoogleChart::widget(array('visualization' => 'LineChart',
             'data' => $graph_data,
            'options' => array(
                'title' => 'My Company Performance2',
                'titleTextStyle' => array('color' => '#FF0000'),
                'vAxis' => array(
                    'title' => 'Scott vAxis',
                    'gridlines' => array(
                        'color' => 'transparent'  //set grid line transparent
                    )),
                'hAxis' => array('title' => 'Scott hAixs'),
                'curveType' => 'function', //smooth curve or not
                'legend' => array('position' => 'bottom'),
            )));
```

Comment: that is what i did in the answer

Comment: after passing this $graph_data to 'data' can not be display on page empty page

Comment: Thanks ..It's Work perfectly ...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
   action

```
$model=Employee::find()->select(['id','sales','expenses'])->all();
    $data[]=["id","sales","expenses"];
    foreach ($model as $item) {
        $data[]=[(string) $item['id'],(int) $item['sales'],(int) $item['expenses']];
    }
    return $this->render('test',['data'=>$data]);
```

view

```
echo GoogleChart::widget(array('visualization' => 'LineChart',
            'data' => $data,
            'options' => array(
                'title' => 'My Company Performance2',
                'titleTextStyle' => array('color' => '#FF0000'),
                'vAxis' => array(
                    'title' => 'Scott vAxis',
                    'gridlines' => array(
                        'color' => 'transparent'  //set grid line  transparent
                    )),
                'hAxis' => array('title' => 'Scott hAixs'),
                'curveType' => 'function', //smooth curve or not
                'legend' => array('position' => 'bottom'),
            )));
```